# Page numbers in landscape

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, landscape

I use `report` class, and now I need to change page orientation (portrait/lanscape) for some pages in my document. I have tried `pdflscape` for that, but there is a problem: page numbers preserve original orientation, instead of being rotated as I have expected. I had tried `lscape` and faced with the same problem. What may cause this strange behavior?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Main chapter}
\section{Ut convallis pharetra augue at aliquet.}

It's all portrait. Some text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci veliturea
adipiscing elit. Ut convallis pharetra augue at aliquet.

%% Landscape area 
\begin{landscape}
 It's all landscape. Some text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci veliturea
 adipiscing elit. Ut convallis pharetra augue at aliquet.
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem on the weekend then switched to koma-class -> problems with header, footer and the numbers were solved. But bit difficult at the beginning, so here is a small example. Hope it will help to switch to koma ;)

```
\documentclass[     12pt,                   %fontsize
                    paper=a4,               %papersize
                    pagesize,               %area
                    DIV=calc,               %relation colls and rows see koma manual
                    liststotocnumbered,     %numbered toc (best solution report sucks over here
                    headsepline,            %header with line
                    footsepline]            %foot with line
                    {scrreprt}              %equals to report

%pagemargins
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}


%Chapter caption is somewhere in the center of the page, so move the shit ;)
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-1cm}}

%If you have a new chapter, the pagestyle will be plain (only pagenumber) according to koma
%To use ur setting redefine the chaperstyle
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 

%Settings for head and foot
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{top left}
\chead{top center}
\ohead{top right}       
\ifoot{bottom left} 
\cfoot{bottom center}
\ofoot{bottom right}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage 
\chapter{First chap}
\section{First sec}
some blank text page is still in portrait

%Save area all setting in myvalues
\storeareas\myvalues

%Change pagestyle to landscape (will create a nee page)
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape, DIV=20} 

some blank text in landscape

%Recover settings
\clearpage
\myvalues

some blank text page is still in portrait

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use `report` indeed.

Comment: Dirty hack: disabled the page number for landscape page (\thispagestyle{empty}) and set it manually (\thepage command.)

Comment: @Denis Can you show us your complete code for that landscape page?

Comment: @cryptic0 I can't use tex markup in comments, so you'll have to split this to lines according tags:
`\begin{landscape}
\centering
% hack for 'lscape' in report class
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}[ph]
\includegraphics{pic_model_choice.pdf}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\caption{Picture caption}
\label{pic_model_choice}
\end{figure}
% hack for 'lscape' in report class (see above)
\thepage
\end{landscape}`

Comment: @Denis Thank you.  I had independently tried approximately the same code, and it had worked.  But the thesis office realized that this was non-standard and scrapped that requirement.