# Rotate title page using landscape with colontitles

Tags: landscape

I'm using landscape to rotate title pages. The problem is that title page is not limited and may require more than one page. And there are different colon-titles in first and others pages. I want the foot and head colon-titles to be rotated when I'm using landscape mode. How can I do it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide a minimal working example (MWE) of what you have already?

Comment: Regarding the header and footer, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209685/landscape-mode-and-page-numbering/209692#209692

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a landscape package, one could lay out the page using tikzpagenodes and only rotate the text.  For example:

[image: title page]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path
  (current page text area.west) +(-\headsep,0pt) node[above,rotate=90,inner sep=0pt] {header}
  (current page text area.east) +(\footskip,0pt) node[above,rotate=90,inner sep=0pt] {\thepage}
  (current page text area.center) node[rotate=90,inner sep=0pt]
    {\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
    \begin{center}
    \Huge A Gigantic, Humongous, Very Large and Really Over-hyped Title!!!
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
A normal page.
\end{document}
```