# How to change the size of the Chapter Number (pedersen style of memoir)

Tags: memoir, chapters

I am creating a document using the memoir class and pedersen style. I am unable to change the size of the chapter number. I tried using code from memoir.cls (see last MWE at [How to change the position of the Chapter Number (pedersen style of memoir)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224771/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-chapter-number-pedersen-style-of-memoir)) but with no luck. Altering line `\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\itshape\colorchapnum}` seems to affect everything but the font size!

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full minimal example others can copy and use for testing. It is not a particularly good idea to just link to someone elses MWE as it may be deleted in the future

Comment: I understand, thank you for your comment. Will do so in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chapter number for this style is not really set using a font size, instead it is resized using `\resizebox` from `graphicx`

Here is the code being used

```
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \sidebar{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \resizebox{!}{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}}}}
```

So here the length `\midchapskip` (which normally is the space between the `chapter 1` line and the actual title, is here controlling the height of the resized chapter number. So you can use say `\setlength\midchapskip{1cm}` to set it to something else. The `pedersen` style sets it to 2cm.

Comment: This solves it. Thank you!

Comment: @vbobanac if it answers your question click the check mark on the answer to mark it solved