# how to keep page header/footer position under pdflscape

Tags: page, pdflscape

I want one page in the middle of my article(the No.2 page in this example) is in landscape style, and other pages in portrait. So the pagckage `pdflscape` is introduced. It's all right for the page and its content, except that the page number in footer rotate too. I think this is the result by pdflscape. But I don't want the position of page header/footer(include page number) changed(as shown on the attached picture). So, is there a better way to get a landscape page with its header/footer keeping in its original position?

MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
some text in portrait
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
some text in landscape
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
some text in portrait
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `sidewaysfigure` or `sidewaystable` with the `rotating.sty` package...

Comment: Thank you @MadyYuvi. I don't want rotate contents of this page, I want to get a landscape page.

Comment: Why do you want the page number to be rotated? That would look rather weird when leafing through the pages. The way it is now, all the page numbers are in the same position on the page.

Comment: The picture I attached is the result of the MWE. You can see that the page number rotated. But what I want is  the page number and its position not to be rotated--just like page numbers on other pages.

Comment: if you want the page number at the bottom you effectively want a new page geometry and and a new pagestyle. This can't be done by simple rotating. You need to calculate where the number should be placed.

Comment: It seems that the package `geometry` can not achieve a certain landscape page when other pages are portrait?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209685/landscape-mode-and-page-numbering, although that only deals with footers.