# How to set pages numbering postion using landscape package?

Tags: tables

Suppose that we have the following table :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|l|l|l|cl|} 
\hline
Test function 
  & Study domain 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                          initial obtained solution (Algorithm 2 )
                          \end{tabular}} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                            Obtained hybrid\\ 
                            optimizer solution\\ 
                            (Algorithm 3 ) 
                            \end{tabular}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                             Objective\\ 
                             function\\ 
                             value  of the\\  
                             solution 
                             \end{tabular}} 
          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* 
\hline
\multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}   Sphere \\    ( dim = 13 )   \end{tabular}} 
  & \multirow{13}{*}{$ [-6,6]^{13} $ } 
    & $N_ter=5 N=20 P=4   $  
      & \multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 
                        $X1=1$ \\ 
                        $X2=-0.15$\\ 
                        $X3=1.07$ \\ 
                        $X4=-1.08$ \\ 
                        $X5=-1.1$ \\ 
                        $X6=0.6$ \\ 
                        $X7=0.5$ \\ 
                        $X8=-0.17$ \\ 
                        $X9=0.12$ \\ 
                        $X10=0.12$ \\ 
                        $X11=-0.28$ \\ 
                        $X12=0.55$ \\ 
                        $X13=0.39  $ \end{tabular} } 
        & \multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 
                          $X1=-0.035$ \\ 
                          $X2=-0.09$ \\ 
                          $X3=-0.0$ \\ 
                          $X4=-0.01$ \\ 
                          $X5=0.05$ \\ 
                          $X6=-0.09$ \\ 
                          $X7=0.05$ \\ 
                          $X8=-0.02$ \\ 
                          $X9=0.3$ \\ 
                          $X10=0.04$ \\ 
                          $X11=-0.07$ \\ 
                          $X12=-0.8$ \\ 
                          $X13=0.4   $ \end{tabular}} 
          & \multirow{13}{*}{$ 0.33  $ } &  \\* 
\cline{3-3}
 &  
   & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} 
     $ \text{Iter} =52 $\\
     $\alpha=0.1$\\
     $\gamma=0.9$    
     \end{tabular} 
     &  &  &  &  \\ 
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\ 
     &&&&&& \\ 
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that i don't know how to set the pages numbering positions at the bottom of the pages.

Thank you for help in advance !

Comment: If this were printed, it would be at the bottom of the page.  IIRC, fancyhdr will automatically rotate the header and footer but does not change the widths.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226678/how-can-i-maintain-the-current-page-nodes-for-portrait-when-temporarily-entering

Comment: @John Kormylo , no i will not print this. This table is a part of some electronic work. i tried \pagestyle{empty} to drop the numbering of pages but i still need a way to set numbering of pages at the bottom as mentionned in the post.

Comment: Is there any possible suggestion ?

Comment: fancyhdr isn't doing the wanted task automatically

Comment: Could someone help plz !

Comment: I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209685/landscape-mode-and-page-numbering  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278113/single-landscape-page-with-page-number-at-the-bottom which should handle the problem.  My first search was for footer instead of everypage.

Comment: the solution there works for just one page , but my table is too long to fit to just one !!