# How to change a certain page to be landscape in a document?

Tags: floats, landscape

I have a figure that I would like to have in a landscape page while the other pages in portrait mode, and keeping the page numbering without rotating it.

I have been trying the answers in [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode) and none are working.

Edit: I don't want to rotate the image itself, I want to have the page rotated in landscape. Please check the image below for reference:

[image: to-do]

Comment: is it a float page? And did you try sideways table?

Comment: yes. and no I haven't tried a sideways, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: which engine do you use? pdflatex?

Comment: yes, I'm using pdflatex

Comment: if you simply want to rotate the content use the rotating package  sidewaysfigure, if you also want to rotate the pdf page in the pdfviewer, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472608/2388

Comment: I have tried the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471472/how-to-make-figures-appear-landscape-properly/472608#472608 to rotate the page itself, and it works, but the page number is also rotated and appears on the left part of the page which I don't want

Comment: This solution solved my problem exactly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209685/landscape-mode-and-page-numbering

Answer (score 1):

A (in my eyes) simple way to do this is the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textheight-\footskip}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{minipage}
}
\clearpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In this MWE I used a `\rotatebox{90}` do turn a `minipage` around by 90°. This minipage has the `\textheight` as its width, so it fits after turned. I subtracted the `\footskip`, so the minipage doesn't get in the page number's way.

**Edit:** Since I seem to have misunderstood the question, here is an approach that actually turns the page around by 90° (based on [this German tutorial](https://golatex.de//wiki/%5CKOMAoptions#Beispiel)):

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\oldwidth}
\setlength{\oldwidth}{\textwidth}
\newlength{\oldheight}
\setlength{\oldheight}{\textheight}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\areaset{\oldheight+\footskip}{\oldwidth-\footskip}

\lipsum[1-2]

\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=portrait}
\recalctypearea
\areaset{\oldwidth}{\oldheight}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This leads to:

[image: turned page]

Comment: I want the page itself to be landscape and not rotate the image

Comment: @netbug I see, then I might have misunderstood your question. I assumed you wanted to have the content in landscape mode only, while keeping the page style, like having a larger diagram in landscape orientation in a book.

Comment: @netbug I added a new approach that actually turns the page around and keeps the page number.

Comment: ok this works, but the problem is that I'm not able to include a figure in the landscape page.